# 宿命 Pronunciation

Tags: words, pronunciation, song-lyrics, ateji, creative-furigana

How do you pronounce “宿命”? Google  says it is pronounced “しゅくめい“ but  I listened it being pronounced as “さだめ“ in a song, which also  is “定め”

Comment: I have never heard 宿命 pronounced 「さだめ」. Are you sure you didn't mishear? [Context, please.](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2189/what-should-i-do-if-i-was-asked-for-the-context-why-is-it-important) What song? The word 定め _can mean_ 宿命 though.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29431/5010

Answer (score 3):

[https://search2.j-lyric.net/index.php?kt=&ct=2&ka=&ca=2&kl=宿命%28さだめ%29&cl=2](https://search2.j-lyric.net/index.php?kt=&ct=2&ka=&ca=2&kl=%E5%AE%BF%E5%91%BD%28%E3%81%95%E3%81%A0%E3%82%81%29&cl=2)
It's ateji, often found in lyrics. There are many lyrics that don't say how to read them, so there are actually more than this.
Other common ateji
[https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22歌詞%22%22当て字%22](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%E6%AD%8C%E8%A9%9E%22%22%E5%BD%93%E3%81%A6%E5%AD%97%22)