# Can 能力 can also be read as "ちから"?

Tags: readings, creative-furigana

I've heard 能力 being read as "ちから" while checking up Japanese subs for Death note. (e.g. そしてキラの能は他に渡った…). But all dictionaries I've consulted say that 能力 is only read as "のうりょく" or "のうりき" and that "ちから" is actually written "力".

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/198/5010 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5565/5010

Comment: So it's stylistic, I see. Thank you very much. I'll probably stick to the standard writing since I'm just a beginner.