# Kanjis read differently: 景色{ばしょ}

Tags: kanji, readings, creative-furigana

I've been studying the song DAN DAN 心魅かれてく from Dragon Ball GT, and I learned that some kanjis are read differently in this song. For example, 景色 (keshiki -> scenery) is read as 場所 (basho -> place)

- 子どものころ大切に想ってた[景色]{ばしょ}を思い出したんだ.
- Kodomo no koro　taisetsu ni omotte ita **basho** o omoidashita n da
- I recalled a **place** that was important to me when I was a child

Does anyone know why this happens and when it's used like this?

Comment: Duplicate/related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/198
 https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29431  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5565

Comment: Please see [this tag info](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tags/creative-furigana/info), too